# How to change text in Chrome Confirm window "XYZ Website says:"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have developed extension that generates confirm window on a current open tab after a certain interval of time. Its working fine but I want to change the text "XYZ website says" to my extension name. How can I do this? Is it possible? [image: chrome confirm window]

Here is my background code:

```
var notifyTimer = setInterval(func, 5 * 1000);
console.log('setinterval ran');


function func() {
  let ActiveTab = getCurrentTab();
  console.log(ActiveTab)

}

const confirmWindow = () => {
  let result = confirm("You've been working for too long on Chrome. Would you like to take a break?");
return result;
}

async function getCurrentTab() {
  let queryOptions = { active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true };
  let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions);
  console.log(tab.url)
  //alert(" Hello!")
  // SOME CODE TO GENERATE CONFIRM WINDOW or ALERT
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    func: confirmWindow
  });

  return tab;
}
```

Comment: did you read this? [Window.confirm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm)

Comment: Yes, I have checked it but I can't find any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to fully customise this text - since the UI is controlled by the browser it's important that it's correctly attributed, and as a result the browser is responsible for choosing this string. However, you can have your extension name appear here:

- In MV2, make sure you call `alert` from the background page rather than a content script.
- In MV3, call `alert` from an [offscreen document](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/). One caveat here is that offscreen documents must be created with a reason and I don't think any of the currently supported reasons are appropriate for alerts. If your alert is part of a larger operation, this could work, but otherwise this approach may not be suitable.

Comment: can we use custom dialogue box in such case?

Comment: Could you elaborate? If you want to add your own dialog to the DOM, you definitely can - just be aware that the page may be able to interfere with any UI you add.

Comment: basically I want to develop extension that generates confirm window or dialogue box kind of element after every 10 seconds. Its working fine but I want to remove the name of the website and put my extension name instead because the confirm window is generated by my extension

Comment: I think the two options are the ones we've mentioned: you could fire the alert from your background script, or add some elements to the DOM with a content script.

Comment: basically I'm getting current/active tab with the help of function "async function getCurrentTab()" and injecting function "const confirmWindow = () => {...}" at active tab. so. its not working in this case

Comment: however, If I simply write this function and call it in background.js then its working fine. this is new function: '''customConf();
function customConf(){
function customConfirm(message, extensionName) {
  return window.confirm(extensionName + " says: " + message);
}

if (customConfirm("You've been working for too long on Chrome. Would you like to take a break?", "GYMPASS")) {
  // The user clicked OK
} else {
  // The user clicked Cancel
}
}''' BUT THIS IS NOT GENENRATING CONFIRM WINDOW AT CURRENT ACTIVE TAB